# Hosting a Spring based webservice app in Amazon Web service(AWS)

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jakarta-ee

There is a J2EE webservice app using spring framework, apache tomcat and mysql db.
Basically, the spring application would give back a json response with some data when request comes from a client app, say android or iphone.

Need to host this in AWS. What's the most scalable and high performing Amazon Web Service (AWS) configuration I should opt for, taking into consideration the following:

1) Minimum response time
2) Capacity to handle maximum concurrent user requests

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

**Some additional info:**

Expected traffic : 1000 concurrent api requests approximately

Complexity of code :Simple straight forward sql queries which gives json response

Whether it is CPU heavy : No

Memory heavy : No

Network heavy : No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS provides many services which enable you to build whole topographies, including [machines](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) of all sizes (from `t1.micro` to `h1.4xlarge`), [load balancers](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), [file hosting](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [databeses](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), and [CDNs](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), among other services.

The most correct configuration to you is very dependant on the expected traffic, budget, complexity of code, whether it is CPU heavy, memory heavy, or network heavy, and a lot of other specifics.

I suggest you start with a single instance of `m3.medium` (a general purpose machine), do your benchmarks, so you can decide if you need to scale up or scale out.

Comment: My recommendation stays the same - do some benchmarks on an `m3.medium` instance, and see if there is a bottleneck - and build up from there.